# C++ linked list head pointer issue value

Tags: c++, linked-list, head

I created my own linked list and I'm having issues getting it to work correctly. When I initialize my linked list the constructor sets the head to null. Yet any time I try to call head it gives me an address instead. Any thoughts. If I cerr right after I initialize it, it comes out as 0, but any time after that is the address. Here's an example.

```
Trip::Trip() {
fileName = "";
cerr << head << endl;
Node<Leg>* head = NULL;
Node<Leg>* endLeg = head;
cerr << head << endl;}

 if (!head) {
        cerr << "if\n";
        insert(head, tempLeg);
        endLeg = head;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "else\n";
        insert(endLeg, tempLeg);
        endLeg = endLeg->getLink();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot possibly call `head` because pointers are not callable. Anyway, what is the [real code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? `head` is only in scope for the first section of that code, and not even all of that.

Comment: Your constructor declares a local variable named `head` (completely unrelated to the member variable by the same name, which I presume class `Trip` has) and sets that to `NULL`. The member variable remains uninitialized.

Comment: you got it igor, I had to take out the types. Noob mistake. Thanks

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but may turn out useful:
Are you aware of existance of STL containers, one of which is linked list? I'm almost sure you know about them, and have a good reason for implementing linked list yourself, but I have personally made that mistake some time ago. I have implemented linked list for one project, not knowing it was readily available in STL. At least I learned in the process.